# Changing the default size and AutoGrowth settings for new SQL Server Databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Our technicians regularly go to client sites to fix EPOS tills. Sometimes they create a new database and import the objects and data via a sync.

Ideally, I'd like to force all new SQL Server 2012 databases to default to our particular initial size and autogrowth settings, not the 4Mb out of the box. The sync routines are executables so we can't rewrite them to apply ALTER DATABASE and our technicians aren't always proficient in SQL Server.

Is there any way to reconfigure the new database defaults? I thought there could be something by tweaking the system tables but can't get anywhere.

Comment: Dan White's answer below is the correct one, but it's unclear if you want to force that on the client server or your server?  The client may not let you modify the model database.

Comment: @JonathanFite We have SQL Server installed on the client tills. The new database will be created from model on the till instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For lack of a better description. Model is copied to create new databases. This ensure they have the same collation, size, data growth settings, and any other  parameter you want to set.